Is it implied that some characters had more "Morty" than others?
In the episode Roy: A Life Well Lived there was one character, "Marta" who seemed to catch on much faster than the others and she became sort of the global leader and elects to live out her life in the game which I assume Rick arranged.
Is it implied that she has much more than the average 1/5 billion of Morty's mind/personality and if so, would Morty not have actually lost a significant part of himself because of this?
Moreover, is she living out the remainder of her life with non-playable characters or did a lot of Morty subpersonalities remain also so she would have company?
Note: It seems pretty clear that being one 5 billionth of Morty does not mean that the character only has that fraction of Morty's intellect. Moreover, the President is yet another character who is more aware of things than others (except Marta).
This episode is not so different than the "Promortious" episode, and even closer are the "Unity" episodes.

We don't know. It's never explored again and the show is basically just an interconnect series of vignettes with little or no continuity between them, except when the plot requires a callback.

The implication I recall, given by the fact that Morty admits an inability to question Rick's suggestions right after exiting the game, was that Marta had as much as Morty's personality as anybody else, but her portion was the one which was exceptionally rebellious against Rick's toxic behaviour. But another interpretation could be that it was an after-effect of Rick spending 100 years or so convincing essentially all the shards of Morty's personality to do what he says.
